# Split Date Column

Tags: r

I am trying to split a date column of the format `Y-M-D` into three separate columns, e.g. I want to convert

```
0001-01-01
```

into

```
0001 01 01
```

It seems it should be straightforward to split by "-" but the `strsplit` function won't work as this is numeric data. Converting to character does not seem to work either. Would the `grep` function work here?

Sorry if this seems a straightforward question. I have trawled through similar problems for half an hour and can't find a simple solution here.

Many thanks.

Comment: I thought we agreed on using Google first in your previous question

Comment: Hi David. As I stated in the question, I googled this problem for half an hour and tried out lots of the suggestions, but couldn't get them to work. This is actually my attempt to finish off what I wanted to do from the last post as I was afraid to ask anything further last time. My apologies for the persistent questions.

Comment: if the data is not a character, your first step should have been to convert it `strsplit(as.character(as.Date('0001-01-01')), '-')[[1]]`

Comment: DJ you should add sample data from your real data set for help. Or just read the linked question.